# How to add a prefix to an order number

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How can i add a prefix to all future order numbers in Magento 1.9.01? I've tried the Database solution described here:

[http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento](http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/)

But this has no effect. New orders have no prefix.

Comment: have you tried by changing store id

Comment: You could hook to the `sales_order_place_after` event and modify the increment id programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to rewrite class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type` and add your custom order numbers logic in the method `fetchNewIncrementId`?

Like

```
public function fetchNewIncrementId($storeId = null)
{
    $incrementId = parent::fetchNewIncrementId($storeId); 

    $incrementId = 'prefix' . $incrementId;

    return $incrementId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Find all order id

SELECT core_store_group.name AS group_name, core_website.name AS website_name, core_store.name AS store_name, core_store.store_id, increment_prefix, increment_last_id, entity_type_code
FROM eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
INNER JOIN core_store ON core_store.store_id = eav_entity_store.store_id
INNER JOIN core_store_group ON core_store_group.group_id = core_store.group_id
INNER JOIN core_website ON core_website.website_id = core_store.website_id
WHERE eav_entity_store.store_id != 0 ORDER BY eav_entity_store.store_id;

Change your Order Prefix on All Stores

UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='SPB'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';

Change your Invoice Prefix on All Stores

UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='SPB'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='invoice';

Change your Shipment Prefix on  All Stores->

UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='SPB'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='shipment';

Change your Credit Memo Prefix on All Stores

UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='SPB'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='creditmemo';
```